# Are tenants responsible for ensuring their guests follow the terms?

Tags: contract-law, rental-property, residential-lease

Are tenants responsible for their guests violating terms in the lease? For example if a lease says "no smoking in the building" and an invited guest smokes, could the tenant be held responsible?

What should a contract contain to show that any guests are the responsibility of the tenants? I've seen "tenants are responsible for their guests actions" but I'm not sure if this is enough as couldn't a tenant argue "I agreed to follow the terms in the lease, but my guest never did, therefore no violation has occurred." Could a contract say "guests are not allowed to smoke" and still be enforceable considering the guests never signed the contract?

Comment: The guests may not have signed the lease; but neither has the landlord agreed to their access to the property, or run a background check.   Was damage caused as a result of a decision of the tenant to permit a guest and to not stop any smoking?  The tenant owes the landlord and the guest owes the tenant.

Comment: Do contracts have to explicitly say "tenants and their guests?"  Seems implicit to me but I'm no lawyer.  If a tenant failed to inform the guest then that's on them--the tenants.

Comment: @user662852 I don't follow you're reasoning. In most places I know of it's actually illegal for a landlord to deny the tenant from having guests. For example if the tenant has family over, the landlord can't say that's not allowed.

Comment: @TimSpriggs I guess I see you're reasoning, are you saying it's the tenants responsibility to ensure everything in the lease is enforced? I guess I'm unclear on that. For example if the landlord comes into the house and breaks a term, such as smoking inside, would that still be the tenants fault?

Comment: "breaks a term?"    Now I'm confused.

Comment: @clipclopshop, where this post fails me is there is no mention of what state we are talking about. If you are in Texas, no you are not responsible for the actions of your tenant and neither is the leasing office. The only relationship recognized by the courts it seems is that between the tenant and landlord, outside of that, nobody is responsible for nobody else unless there is an illegal act being committed then the leasing office can be fined if they were negligent. The Texas court does not go by the broken window theory which is good except in matters such as apartment complexes.

Comment: @clipclopshop, it seems to be societal in Texas too. Case in point, my first and only time ever living in an apartment complex. I saw a broken window in my building, I asked the leasing manager what that was all about and he shot at me with this attitude like what business is it of yours. I shot back with a glance of "have you forgotten who pays your salary or am I living here rent free? So yes it is my business". I think he took the hint and said oh the tenants friend broke the glass but we will be fixing it soon. Hmm, he got the message, can Texas courts maybe get it?

Comment: @clipclopshop, so the question for the Texas landlord-tenant court system is why am I a great citizen if I am concerned about what is going on in my neighborhood if I rent or own a single family home, but I am somehow treated as a moron who needs to shut up and pay his rent and mind his business if I express that same community concern in an apartment complex and how does the fact that most apartment complexes are owned by real estate holding companies and hedge funds weigh into that difference in viewpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a starting point, if you agree to do something in a contract then that is what you must do. Therefore, if you sign a lease that says "no smoking in the building" then you must make sure that there is no smoking in the building.

However, you are not required to do things that are impossible, either physically impossible or legally impossible. So your obligation is to ensure no smoking in the building to the limit of your power.

If you have guests, you must ensure they do not smoke, by telling them not to if you know they are smokers and by telling them not to if you discover them smoking or about to smoke. As your guests, they have a legal obligation to follow your lawful and reasonable requests; if they do not then you can revoke your permission for them to be on your premises. If they then refuse to leave then they are trespassing and you can call the police to have them removed. If you did this, then you would not be responsible because you have done all that is legally possible.